# How to get file size before upload on s3 bucket in nodeJs + sequelize+graphql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, graphql, sequelize.js

Validate file size before upload on s3 bucket.currently use this code for get file size:

```js
const {
  createReadStream,
  filename
} = await file
const stream = await createReadStream()
let chunk = [];
let conLength;
stream.on('data', data => chunk.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunk);
    conLength = buffer.length;
  });
console.log(conLength)
const url = await uploadToS3(stream, filename)
assetRequestUrls.push(url)
```

But file size get in conLength variable that use only in function not used outside function. So, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `console.log` the filesize

```
const fs = require('fs')

const { size } = fs.statSync(filename)
console.log(size)
```